# How to find and output lists including the max number(of all lists)? Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I need to find the max number in a list of lists in Prolog, and then 'print' (output in a new list) the lists that include this max number.

For example: lists_with_max([[1,2,3],[2,3,44],[44,5,6]],Lists).
Should output: Lists = [[2,3,44],[44,5,6]]

Code below is the closest I could think of that works and has no errors, but it's obviously wrong because everytime it finds a new max and then outputs wrong lists.

'max' finds the max number in a list.
'flat' "flattens" a list.
'maxl' finds the max number in a list of lists.

```
max([X], X).
max([H|T], H):-
    max(T, MaxT),
    H > MaxT.
max([H|T], MaxT):-
    max(T, MaxT),
    H =< MaxT.

flat([], []).
flat([H|T], [H|LT]):-
    atomic(H),
    flat(T, LT).
flat([H|T], L):-
    flat(T, LT),
    not(atomic(H)),
    flat(H, LH),
    append(LH, LT, L).

maxl(List,Max):-
    flat(List,Newlist),
    max(Newlist,Max).

lists_with_max([],[]).
lists_with_max([H|T],[H|L]):-
    maxl([H|T],Max),
    member(Max,H),
    lists_with_max(T,L).
lists_with_max([_H|T],L):-
    lists_with_max(T,L).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another approach using builting predicates [max_list/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=max_list/2), [maplist/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/3), [include/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=include/3) and [memberchk/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=memberchk/2):

```
lists_with_max(LL, LL1):-
  maplist(max_list, LL, ML),
  max_list(ML, M),
  include(memberchk(M), LL, LL1).
```

Comment: I like this better than my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you went off the rails a bit with `maxl/2` and `flat/2`, you don't really need them to solve your problem. This isn't, IMO, a great example of something you can do by throwing a bunch of recursion at the problem, you really are going to have to look through all the lists, find the max element, and then look through them all again. Your `max/2` is fine though.

So, let's find the max element:

```
setof(Max, L^(member(L, Lists), max(L, Max)), Maxes),
```

This is a meta-predicate, it's just going to look through all the lists for the max of that list, and make a new list of the maxes of each list. I think good Prolog should have a fluent quality; if you reworded your query into something more like logic, you would have something like "The Maxes of the Lists is a list containing the max of each List" and eventually you would arrive at something like what you see there. The `L^` is saying, we do *not* want to group this by the list `L` it generates (there will come other times in your life as a Prolog programmer where you will want this grouping). Probably using `findall/3` would have the same effect, but I like `setof/3` more.

Next, let's find the max-of-maxes:

```
max(Maxes, Max),
```

Pretty straight-forward. Now let's find all the lists that have the maximum in them:

```
setof(L, (member(L, Lists), member(Max, L)), Result).
```

This is another one like the first, where we're saying "find me all the lists L such that L is in Lists and Max is in L". Putting it all together we have:

```
lists_with_max(Lists, Result) :-
    setof(Max, L^(member(L, Lists), max(L, Max)), Maxes),
    max(Maxes, Max),
    setof(L, (member(L, Lists), member(Max, L)), Result).
```

Another way of doing `max/2`, which I include here mostly to show you another way to think about Prolog because it is way, way less efficient and sort of terrible is this:

```
max(List, Max) :-
    member(Max, List),
    \+ (member(Y, List), Y > Max).
```

This isn't great style, but it does demonstrate that you can sometimes tell Prolog what you want rather than how to find it. This says the Max of List is the member of Max of List such that there is no member Y of List which is greater than it. Food for thought, I hope.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! Although still a bit confusing for me because I haven't seen almost any of these predicates before.

Comment: @MichailKaravas there's really only three predicates in there that you weren't using: `member/2`, which is the most common form of list iterator we have in Prolog, `\+/1`, which is negation, and `setof/3`, which is a second-order predicate for finding solutions. All of these are pretty common, if you've just started with Prolog, you'll probably encounter them pretty soon (and probably in that order).